# Will $\int_{4}^{10}\int_{2}^{y/2} (5x + 2y) \, dx dy$ and $\int_{2}^{5}\int_{2x}^{10} (5x + 2y) \, dy dx$ give the same answer?

Tags: calculus, integration

The following double integrals are meant to describe a triangle with points at $(2, 10),~(5, 10)$, and $(2, 4)$.

$$\int_{4}^{10}\int_{2}^{y/2} (5x + 2y) \, dx dy \\[16pt]
\int_{2}^{5}\int_{2x}^{10} (5x + 2y) \, dy dx$$

I know that the second integral is correct, but I was wondering if the first integral will also evaluate to the same answer and if it is a correct way to solve the problem.

Comment: When you write "$1/2y$", do you mean $(1/2)y$ or $1/(2y)$.  Strict application of order of operations gives the former, but many, many people incorrectly interpret it as the latter.

Comment: I mean (1/2)y! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The two integrals are equivalent. They integrate over the given triangle region. They differ only in integrating order in terms of $x$ and $y$, yet producing the same result,

$$\int_{4}^{10}dy \int_{2}^{1/2y} (5x + 2y) \, dx  =
\int_{2}^{5}dx\int_{2x}^{10} (5x + 2y) \, dy =279 $$